# com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to my object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have JSON file looks like

```
{
    "SUBS_UID" : {
        "featureSetName" : "SIEMENSGSMTELEPHONY MULTISIM",
        "featureName" : "MULTISIMIMSI",
        "featureKey" : [{
                "key" : "SCKEY",
                "valueType" : 0,
                "value" : "0"
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

So the key is a String "SUBS_ID" and the value is a model called FeatureDetails which contains attributes "featureSetName,featureName,...".
So i read from the JSON file using google.json lib like this,

```
HashMap<String, FeatureDetails> featuresFromJson = new Gson().fromJson(JSONFeatureSet, HashMap.class);
```

then I'm trying to loop over this HashMap getting the value and cast it to my FeatureDetails model,

```
for (Map.Entry entry : featuresFromJson.entrySet()) {
                    featureDetails = (FeatureDetails) entry.getValue();
                }
```

and here is my FeatureDetails Model,

```
public class FeatureDetails {

    private String featureSetName;
    private String featureName;
    private ArrayList<FeatureKey> featureKey;
    private String groupKey;
    private String groupValue;

    public FeatureDetails() {
        featureKey =  new ArrayList<FeatureKey>();
    }

    public ArrayList<FeatureKey> getFeatureKey() {
        return featureKey;
    }

    public void setFeatureKey(ArrayList<FeatureKey> featureKey) {
        this.featureKey = featureKey;
    }

    public String getGroupKey() {
        return groupKey;
    }

    public void setGroupKey(String groupKey) {
        this.groupKey = groupKey;
    }

    public String getGroupValue() {
        return groupValue;
    }

    public void setGroupValue(String groupValue) {
        this.groupValue = groupValue;
    }

    public String getFeatureName() {
        return featureName;
    }

    public void setFeatureName(String featureName) {
        this.featureName = featureName;
    }

    public String getFeatureSetName() {
        return featureSetName;
    }

    public void setFeatureSetName(String featureSetName) {
        this.featureSetName = featureSetName;
    }
}
```

but i got an exception "com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to com.asset.vsv.models.FeatureDetail".

Comment: Your code is very weird.  You initialize featureDetails to a new instance of FeatureDetails but then discard that in favour of the Mpap value immediately.

Comment: can you please post the code for FeatureDetails?

Comment: @Taylor my mistake it has no need to intilaize it by new

Comment: You're asking gson for a hashmap, how do you expect it to know about your FEatureDetails class?  Suggest you go over the gson user guide.

Comment: @OzanTabak i just edited the Question adding feature details model

Comment: I knew it would not know about it that why i use casting.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try this:

```
HashMap<String, FeatureDetails> featuresFromJson = new Gson().fromJson(JSONFeatureSet, new TypeToken<Map<String, FeatureDetails>>() {}.getType());
```

and when you going through your hash map do this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, FeatureDetails> entry : featuresFromJson.entrySet()) {
                    FeatureDetails featureDetails = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: It throws an exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap"

Comment: i see (lol) then `new TypeToken<HashMap<String, FeatureDetails>() {}.getType()` will do

Comment: Wierd that it works when i convert it to HashMap, doesn't Hashmap extends from Map??

Comment: A `HashMap` implements `Map` interface, the reason i loled is that google has to be different :) so in this case when you convert from `Json` to `Object` using `TypeToken` and specifically state that it is `Map`, `fromGson` returns `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedHashTreeMap` which is not assignable to `HashMap`. So the proper way of doing this would be `Map<String, FeatureDetails> featuresFromJson = new Gson().fromJson(str, new TypeToken<Map<String, FeatureDetails>>() {}.getType());`

Comment: Some background: LinkedHashTreeMap is a class that exists in Gson to defend against hash-collision DoS attacks. It performs like HashMap in the common case and like TreeMap in the worst case.
http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/12/huge-portions-of-web-vulnerable-to-hashing-denial-of-service-attack/

Comment: tanx for help , just a bit problem , i think this : new TypeToken<`Map`<String, FeatureDetails>>;(return error for me) should change to :  new TypeToken<`HashMap`<String, FeatureDetails>>;(after change was right)

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're seeing this is because you're telling GSON to deserialize the JSON structure using the structure of a `HashMap` in the line

```
... = new Gson().fromJson(JSONFeatureSet, HashMap.class);
                                          ^^
                                          Right here
```

As a result, GSON has no idea that the sub objects in the JSON are anything other than simple key-value pairs, even though the structure may match the structure of your `FeatureDetails` object.

One solution is to create a model which wraps your `FeatureDetails` object, which will act as the root of the entire structure. This object might look something like this:

```
public class FeatureDetailsRoot{
    private FeatureDetails SUBS_UID; // poor naming, but must match the key in your JSON
}
```

And finally, you'd pass that model's class:

```
= new Gson().fromJson(JSONFeatureSet, FeatureDetailsRoot.class)
```

**Update**

In answer to your question in the comment regarding the ability to add / have multiple `FeatureDetails` objects, the problem presently is that your JSON does not reflect that kind of structure. Meaning, the `"SUBS_UID"` key points to a single object, not an array objects. If you would like to have this ability, then your json will need to be altered so that it shows an array of objects, like this:

```
{
    "SUBS_UID" : [{
       "featureSetName" : "Feature set name #1",
       ...attributes for feature #1
     },
     {
       "featureSetName" : "Feature set name #2",
       ...attributes for feature #2
     },
     ...other features
     ]
}
```

And then you can simply alter the root class so that it contains a list of `FeatureDetails` objects, like so:

```
public class FeatureDetailsRoot{
    private List<FeatureDetails> SUBS_UID;
}
```

Let me know if that makes sense (or whether I've misunderstood you)

Comment: If i got what you said then I thought about this solution, but it will makes my code some how static(every time I want to add entry to the hashmap I have to add it to the root class)

Comment: @Islam Do you mean that it can be possible to have more than one `FeatureDetails` object in the root; meaning an array of `FeatureDetails`?

Comment: Yes I do mean that, the Hashmap retrieved from JSON contains many keys and each key mapped to feature details model

Comment: Man your update is great it added something new about GSON lib to me, but what i ment is that the JSON file may have many keys and each key mapped to its FeatureDetails model.

Comment: @Islam Ohh ok, sorry I misunderstood. Are you able to know what those keys might be at run time, or is it possible for the JSON to change structure (meaning variable number of keys) each time? If it is variable, then I think you have two choices: either restructure the JSON so that it is a JSON array like I suggested, or if you cannot do that (or it is more trouble than it is worth), go with the answer user1631616 posted.

Comment: No its not possible at run time, I load this JSON file when i lunch my application, and according to some performance issues I will not be able to load it at run time.

Answer (score 2):

```
(objectName as Map<String, Any>).get("fieldName")
```

Answer (score 0):

the code is in Kotlin:
use `val type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, FoodLogEntry>>() {}.type
            Gson().fromJson(dataStr, type)`

instead of `val type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, FoodLogEntry>>() {}.type
            Gson().fromJson(dataStr, type)`
note: HashMap instead of Map