# com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to object

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-client

I have created the following restful jersy client the return array of object ,it works but it return string value ,I have changed it to hgson but get the following error in   this line

```
ScoreRouteRulefile scoreRouteRulefile=scoreRouteRulefiles.get(i);
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.innvo.drools.ScoreRouteRulefile

```
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/adap/api/getQuery/"+filterId);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);

        String output =  response.getEntity(String.class);

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List>() {}.getType();

        List<ScoreRouteRulefile> scoreRouteRulefiles = new Gson().fromJson(output, listType);

         for(int i=0;i<scoreRouteRulefiles.size();i++){
            ScoreRouteRulefile scoreRouteRulefile=scoreRouteRulefiles.get(i);
        }
```

Comment: Please do some research before posting a question.  You have exact same question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796590/com-google-gson-internal-linkedhashtreemap-cannot-be-cast-to-my-object)

Comment: i did but get Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected   array but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 78 path $[0]

Comment: Then you need to adjust your question accordingly.  There is no such information exists in your question.  This exception would happen because of the invalid structure of your JSON.  Check the validity of your JSON string.